# What asset would you recommend to save entire scene in unity?

Tags: serialization, unity-game-engine, save

So I need save game system that can save entire scene's current state.

Like picture or capture that state.

Mainly my scene is consisted of 2d textures, images, ui elements, and just gameobject that has just bunch of code scripts (manager scripts to control the game).  My game is 2d simple game.

At past I used this asset,

https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/kr/#!/content/3675

But this stops support and does not compatible with unity5.0~

I checked above asset's update version in reply but that don't work too.

Any other solutions? Recommend?

Thanks.

Comment: It is quite easy to do by yourself. Finding all Transforms, saving its position, scale, rotation, parent, Monobehaviours on it wth public not hidden in inspector variables.

Comment: You could already discard all static items since there are not meant to move or change. And I mean static objects not static in classes.

Comment: mainly my scene is consisted of 2d textures, images, ui elements, and just gameobject that has just bunch of code scripts (manager scripts to control the game).  My game is 2d simple game.